# mvc 5 code first userid as a Foreign Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want UserId column to be a foreign key, Mvc Membership's User's Id column.
How can I achive this?

My IdentityModels:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Add a reference to the `ApplicationUser` and specify the ForeignKey:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Add the new model to your DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<TestModel> TestModels { get; set; }

    /* rest of class */
}
```

And you should be good-to-go (less migrations/database updates).

Comment: Thanks, this also works in reverse, if you want the AspNetUsers table reference to another table with a foreign key, add same code to the ApplicationUser class changing the relevant types. Just make sure you define a key column in the other table.

Comment: @brad how to add foreign key relationship if my entities are in another class library project and Identity tables are in web project? Please let me know if you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea of using `[ForeignKey]` attribute in `TestModel`. It's better to do this using Fluent API. Here is the code to add `UserId` column in `TestModel` table and add a Foreign Key constraint:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual TestModel TestModel { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TestModel> TestModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasOptional(m => m.TestModel)
            .WithRequired(m => m.ApplicationUser)
            .Map(p => p.MapKey("UserId"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might run into error CS1061 when scaffold using Visual Studio 2015, Ater following the great answer :
/*************************/

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Add the new model to your DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<TestModel> TestModels { get; set; }

    /* rest of class */
}
```

/*****************************/ 
Solution 
Delete the controller and views of the affected controller,
Rename  to  in DbContext
to look like this

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Users>
```

Restart VS, then scaffold.

Disclaimer: Am not the author of above solution just edited and posted for someone' benefit